# How to obfuscate an Android Library module

Tags: android, gradle, proguard, aar

I have 3 modules: 2 Android applications and 1 Android Library that I'll call "common module" in this question.

The Android Library module is included in the two Android applications and  provides shared functionalities across the two applications. Both applications depend on the common module using: `implementation project(":mylibrary")`

Since the Android Library module contains sensitive functionalities, I'm trying to obfuscate it in order to make this part of the application harder to reverse-engineer. At the same time, I don't want to obfuscate the 2 Android applications  as they are large and testing all functionalities after obfuscation is time consuming and not worth the effort.

I have enabled `minifyEnabled` in `build.gradle` file of the common module and added keep rules to `proguard-rules.pro` file. When I run `assembleRelease` task on it, the resulting `.aar` file is obfuscated but when I try `assembleRelease` on either of the applications, the classes from the common library are not obfuscated at all.

The only solution that I can think of is that I generate an `.aar` file of the common library and manually import it in the applications, which will work but it requires generating a new `.aar` file each time I make a change to the common module and importing it to several applications which can be time consuming and prone to human errors. I will also have to keep track of mapping files on each release of the `.aar` files.

Any thoughts on how I can either automate this process, or configure the common module to get obfuscate when a consumer module is being built?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

try `releaseImplementation project(":mylibrary")`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried `releaseImplementation`, still no obfuscation.